# Notepad malfunction in Windows 11

Tags: notepad

I recently moved to Windows 11 Operating System.

**Notepad Version:  11.2311.35.0**

The new Notepad (not Notepad ++) has been giving me a hard time.

There is one major bug here.

I have the Notepad pinned to my taskbar.

[image]

Whenever I open the Notepad from my Taskbar, I see the previously opened Notepad files too. You can see the image to understand what I mean.

What should I do to remove this technical bug ?

Is there a way to switch back to the older notpad of Windows 10, and if so, will that affect my existong Notepade files ?

Any suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set your preferences for startup to start a new "session" (note that settings are now accessible via the little "gear wheel" icon, in the top right corner).

[image]